# How do I remove everything after a certain character?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, character

Code:

```
with open('list.csv', "w") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerows(results)
```

**Example**

If my output is `123,456789`, how would I remove everything after the comma?

Comment: what does `results` look like?

Comment: hi perhaps something like `s.split(',', 1)[0]`

Comment: Everything after the comma on that line, or in the entire file?

Comment: In the entire file

Comment: Why are you writing it in the first place? Why don't you just remove the second element of each row in `results`?

Answer (score 1):

you can just use the first element only (by slicing) when you write the rows.

Do something like this:

```
with open('list.csv', "w") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerows(map(lambda row:row[:1], results))
```

Comment: This did it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you use a slice `row[:1]` instead of `[row[0]]` in your lambda, this will work even if there are blank rows.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `result` is your output, this will do:

```
result = result.split(',')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` to split the text where the comma is, then take the first piece:

```
with open('list.csv', "w") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerows(results.split(',')[0])
```